varioref does not work with a new list when using enumerate
I created a new list because I needed a list 5 levels deep:
\newlist{creedoor}{enumerate}{5}%
\setlist[creedmoor,1]{label={\textbf{\arabic*.}},ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[creedmoor,2]{label={\alph*.},ref=\theenumi.\alph*}
\setlist[creedmoor,3]{label={\roman*.},ref=\theenumii.\roman*}
\setlist[creedmoor,4]{label={\arabic*.},ref=\theenumiii.\arabic*}
\setlist[creedmoor,5]{label={\alph*.},ref=\theenumiii.\alph*}
\setlist{nosep}%document}

Now, using the varioref package, it I try to do this:
\begin{creedmoor}
\item \label{item:first item}
\end{creedmoor}

and them at a later place in the document enter"
see item \vref{item:first item}

the output os "0.a"
How can I get varioref to realize creedmoor is a new list and correctly list the line numbers?

Please make your code compilable (if possible), or at least complete it with \documentclass{...}, the required \usepackage's, \begin{document}, and \end{document}. That may seem tedious to you, but think of the extra work it represents for the users willing to give you a hand. Help them help you: remove that one hurdle between you and a solution to your problem.

There's a typo in your code: In the \newlist directive you use creedoor, but in the setlist directives you use creedmoor. Please fix.

And shouldn't the instances of ref=\theenum... be ref=\thecreedmoor...?

You shouldn't use enumi and similar names, but creedmoori and so on.
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[a6paper]{geometry}% just to produce smaller pictures
\usepackage{enumitem}
\usepackage{varioref}

\newlist{creedmoor}{enumerate}{5}
\setlist[creedmoor,1]{label=\textbf{\arabic*.},ref=\arabic*}
\setlist[creedmoor,2]{label=\alph*.,ref=\thecreedmoori.\alph*}
\setlist[creedmoor,3]{label=\roman*.,ref=\thecreedmoorii.\roman*}
\setlist[creedmoor,4]{label=\arabic*.,ref=\thecreedmooriii.\arabic*}
\setlist[creedmoor,5]{label=\alph*.,ref=\thecreedmooriv.\alph*}
\setlist{nosep}

\begin{document}

\begin{creedmoor}
\item \label{item:first item}
  \begin{creedmoor}
    \item \label{item:second}
  \end{creedmoor}
\end{creedmoor}

see item \vref{item:first item}

see item \vref{item:second}

\newpage

see item \vref{item:first item}

see item \vref{item:second}

\end{document}



+1. \setlist[creedmoor,5]{label=\alph*.,ref=\thecreedmooriii.\alph*} should be \setlist[creedmoor,5]{label=\alph*.,ref=\thecreedmooriv.\alph*}, right?

@Mico I guess so, I just copied the original.
